The preview link on the community digests page is broken
Clicking on one of the preview links on the network community digests page results in a blank white box filling the screen and an error being logged to the console.
This is from clicking the preview link for Ask Different, but every link yields an identical result:


It also looks like you can't escape. You can't click out of it to make it go away. I need to refresh the page.

Repro here, Brave (chrome-based), Version 1.71.123 Chromium: 130.0.6723.116 (Official Build) (64-bit), no blockers. Opera behaves differently, opening the preview correctly, but it won't dismiss.

Reason: SE still using (at least there in se.com) ancient version of fancybox (jQuery plugin) which dates back to 2010 or so, and it finally broke. (JS error causing the box to not load)

It's fixed now. 
It would've been fixed last week if I had remembered to actually deploy stackexchange.com to production, but let's pretend that didn't happen.
Thanks for the report!

Well if we pretend that didn't happen, then you fixed this at a velocity of infinity bugs per second. Impressive!

As a workaround until this gets fixed, you can right click the "preview" link and choose "Open link in new tab":



Or, if you're using mouse with three buttons, middle click the link.
